# How to create ETL programatically in RavenDB 3.5?

Tags: c#, console, ravendb, ravendb-studio, ravendb-http

I have a RavenDB database "XYZ" with a collection "Products". On a certain point in my console application. I was to create another RavenDB database "DataStaging_XYZ" and replicate the "Products" collection onto it.

Here is how I am creating the "DataStaging_XYZ" database.

documentStore.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin.EnsureDatabaseExists(databaseName);

**I am not sure how to enable "ETL" for "Products" in my "XYZ" database.**
This is how I am enabling when I have Raven studio but I want to do this step programatically in my C# application.

[image]

Thanks in advance.